# is it possible to replicate a view from a SQL server to another one?

Tags: sql-server, replication

I know a view is composed of tables.
Can I replicate a view anyway?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For SQL SERVER 2008
Have a look at the link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152559.aspx. This explains all the objects that can be replicated.

For SQL Server 2005
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152559(SQL.90).aspx

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

You would need to add the view to the Publication (along with the underlying tables)

Answer (score -1):

What you want to do is replicate the table and create a view of the replicated table.

Comment: While that is an option, you can also replicate just the view. See replicating "Indexed Views as Tables" in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152559.aspx